# Подскажите пожалуйстаб. Как редактиовать код в сервере, я хочу редактировать проект фронтенд в сервере

Tags: reactjs, frontend, веб-сервер

я с помощью firezilla подключаюсь к серверу Sftp код меняется в сервере но нечего не меняется в сайте

Comment: значит не тот код меняете)